# Improve Audio Recording quality in android?

Tags: android, voice-recording, android-mediarecorder

I am using the `MediaRecorder` for audio recording in android. I receive very poor audio quality when I record. I checked iPhone recording, and it is very good, but in android I receive horrible sound.

For sound recording I use:

```
 recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
 recorder.setOutputFile(path);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();
```

How do I improve Audio Recording quality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [very poor quality of audio recorded on my droidx using MediaRecorder, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010145/very-poor-quality-of-audio-recorded-on-my-droidx-using-mediarecorder-why)

Comment: did you get any solution? and improvment in audio quality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one -

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Comment: i have tried it and now it raise another problem... it not record the voice

Comment: Have you give the permission in `Manifest.xml`

Comment: ya ... record audio and writeexternal

Comment: For, my code it's not working na? Just checkout my updated code.

Comment: hi ! now it s working now it play but not getting any difference. so how can i improve my sound quality?

Comment: can you tell me what i do to remove background noice?

Comment: Background noice? That means?

Comment: when you record sound, background noise also record .... so how to prevent from this>

Comment: That how can we reduce that. Because, that's also a sound. If you want to reduce that. You must record the voice with alone or record with empty room. I think so.

Comment: I tried this recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax()); but this gives me IllegalStateException(invalid audio encoder) can you tell me how to improve sound quality and its playback quality

Comment: `recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);` That would set the bitrate to 16 bits per second, which is really bad..

Comment: It gives `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid audio encoder`

Comment: To clarify, you should probably do something like `recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16 * 44100);` rather than using 16. 16 is probably the bit depth but far too low for the bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

Android has mainly supported 3 sound formats (i mean from creation point of view) : 3gp, mp4 and amr. Actually all there quality is very poor, so nothing to do about that.

Anyway you can use external mp3 codecs or save it as wave file. Sounds will be more clear but such codec(wav) will require large voice file in comporations of three formats mentioned above.

Comment: i am not agree with you because in coding world, this is possible

Comment: I would like to know how then

Comment: as SpK told ... . . . and still not i am satisfied with his answer,i will try to more explorer...