# How to improve the audio quality on android

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiomanager

I am doing voice recording application on android using AudioRecorder Class and have worked with different Sample Rates 44100,32000,24000,16000 and 8000. The Sample Rate 44100 gives good quality audio but it takes very large size but other samples rate give bad and very bad quality audios with acceptable file sizes.

Before you say Possible of duplicate questions i have seen the following Links:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437888/improve-android-audio-recording-quality)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389572/improve-audio-recording-quality-in-android)

But the referred links are different from question.

my questions is how to get good quality audio with small file size  for the sample rates such as 32000,24000 and 8000?

or Is there any way compress the wav file from large size to small one?.

my code sample:

```
tempbufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(16000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
........
mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,tempbufferSize);
mAudioRecord.startRecording();
.....
```

i have refered the [Link.](http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.in/2011/12/audio-recording-part-2.html)

please help me.

Comment: "How to improve the audio quality on android" - get a new pair of headphones.

Comment: @H2CO3, please help with related comments. do not write these types unrelated comments. please.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that when you increase the sample rate you get more samples per second and that effectively increases the size of the file. The approach is more quality, more data.

**Some references for compression:**

---

http://www.eetimes.com/design/analog-design/4017792/Audio-Compression-Algorithm-Overview

http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/index.php

http://flac.sourceforge.net/license.html <-- BSD license / lossless

http://jflac.sourceforge.net/ << Apache license / lossless

Answer (score 0):

WAV is pure uncompressed audio data so without sacrificing quality, file sizes will be quite large. You could record to MPEG4 using MediaRecorder and setOutputFormat()

Look at:

[MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

[OutputFormat MPEG4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html#MPEG_4)

Hope that helped

Comment: Actually, I see that link 2 in your question uses MediaRecorder. Does this not solve your problem?

Comment: I need pause and resume features in audio recording thats why i do not go ahead with MediaRecorder. is possible to combine mp4 files while pause and resume?. if this is possible please tell me some samples?. please

Comment: I see. It does have Start and Stop features, but after calling Stop you have to reconfigure it as if you were starting again. You could concatenate the files after each session. Another option is to record in WAV and then after you have finished, use JLayer to convert the WAV file to MP3. JLayer: http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html

Comment: please tell me how to concatenate the files after each session for Mp4  files using MediaRecorder. it would help me a lot.

Comment: the mpeg-4 spec is http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-4/mpeg-4.htm#10.9 here. You would have to know the file header structure, which i'm really not sure about.

Comment: You could also use 3GPP, which I think might be easier. Again, you will have to find out the header format.