# how to record audio file with better quality in android?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, aac, android-audiorecord

I am creating one application which play recorded file on Android to iphone and vice-versa.

now I am using ,

```
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

file recorded using this code having size 85 kb /15 sec and a very poor quality.

if I use ,

```
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

then file size is 25kb/15 sec and quality much better than aac.
but problem is that **AMR** is not playable in iPhone.

So please suggest recording schema for Android having better quality, affordable size and can play on iPhone also.

Answer (score 18):

Increase the recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(value) if you want to change the quality.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

EDIT:

Another option is to add a converter to your app. Convert AMR to AAC.

Comment: Thanks Jermaine,

 audioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
 audioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);

try this but having much noise in sound.

Comment: Try to adjust the sampling rate and the bit rate. and find a better place to record.

Comment: The bit rate is measured in bits per second, not kb per second, so should be around 128000 rather than 16 as shown here (a value of 16 would correspond to bit depth).

Comment: ``recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());`` crashes the app on my side; however ``recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);`` works almost perfectly.

Comment: Get max causes "Invalid audio encoder". Android 8.1.

Comment: EncodingBitRate is too small. Quality of audio is too bad. Use higher EncodingBitRate

Answer (score 5):

This link is very useful: [Android supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

This section gives us more information about audio and video formats.